# Correct usage of PM2 for Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I am considering switching from forever to [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) to keep my node application up and running.

I am confused about the following recommended methods for starting a process:

```
$ pm2 start app.js -i 4 # Daemonize pm2 and Start 4 clustered instances of app.js
                        # You can also pass the 'max' params to start
```

Could someone explain to me what is a clustered instance of app.js? How many instances should I start? 1? Max?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clustered app means duplicating the application to use each cpu instead of only one,

If you do:

```
$ pm2 start app.js
```

It will only launch one application

If you do:

```
$ pm2 start app.js -i max
```

It will launch the maximum number applications depending on the number of cpus available, so if it's a networked app, requests will be balanced between all processes!

Comment: Note that the `cluster` module is experimental yet, use it in production under your own risk. The usual way to work with node is by forking, so e.g.: `pm2 start app.js -x max`

Comment: cluster module is now fully operational but pm2 suffers  from serious memory consumption issues pros would be  very  precise in accordance with nodejs deployment module